# Simple get/post request blocked in python 3 but not in python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm working on a simple web scraper in python 3 but when I send a get or a post request, the response is 403. In python 2 works fine though. I'm using the same version of requests libraries in both versions. I have
also tried with `Verify=False/True` but the difference in both versions remains.

requests = 2.22.0

certifi = 2019.9.11

```
from requests import get
url = 'https://www.gamestop.com/'
header = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Host': 'www.gamestop.com'
}
res = get(url, headers=header, verify=False).status_code
print(res)
# 403 when using python 3.7.4
# 200 when using python 2.7.16
```

**Edit by @blhsing:**

The list below keeps track of which specific Python versions work and which versions fail according to the comments. So far successes and failures have been consistent for each specific Python version across platforms.

Feel free to edit this section of the question with your own results along with the specific Python versions used to produce the results.

```
2.7.14 works (blhsing)
2.7.16 works (repl.it)
3.6.5 works (blhsing)
3.6.8 fails (Reinderien and blhsing)
3.7.3 works (wim and blhsing)
3.7.4 fails (repl.it and blhsing)
3.8.0 fails (OP)
```

Demo on repl.it: [Python 2.7.16](https://repl.it/@blhsing/DapperLikelyBit) and [Python 3.7.4](https://repl.it/@blhsing/EarlyMessyApplescript)

Comment: It should be noted that this works in Python 3.6 but not in 3.7.

Comment: I get "Access Denied" even in Firefox - after few runs code in Python 3.7. I didn't try in Firefox before running Python - maybe I'm blocked after using Python code or maybe it blocks for other reason - wrong IP, wrong country, problem on server.

Comment: using Google I found that some people has problem to access this page even in browser for different reason.

Comment: @blhsing yep that's weird, i guess i'll go with 3.6 then, thx for note

Comment: That's strange. Use Wireshark and compare the requests sent by Python 3.6 and 3.7. There's gotta be some difference the server is picking up on.

Comment: No repro. I get 200 OK in both Python 2.7 and Python 3.7.

Comment: I get a 403 in Python 3.6.8. Given the above highly variable results, I somehow doubt that it's the version of Python actually making a difference here.

Comment: @wim Interesting. Here's a demo I just put up on repl.it: [Python 2.7.16 demo](https://repl.it/@blhsing/DapperLikelyBit) and [Python 3.7.4 demo](https://repl.it/@blhsing/EarlyMessyApplescript)

Comment: @Reinderien Interesting. The code works in Python 3.6.5 for me but not Python 3.7.4 in Windows. It's highly repeatable from the same host and environment.

Comment: @wim Which specific version of Python 3.7 are you running? I'd like to install that specific version on my own to see if I can get a 200 OK too.

Comment: I've not been able to get a single 200 using either 3.6, 3.7 or 2.7. FWIW, I see that Firefox is using HTTP2, and requests is only capable of HTTP1.1 - that's another factor we should eliminate.

Comment: @Reinderien I just installed Python 3.6.8 as you do and got a 403 as well. Switched back to 3.6.5 and got 200 again. All using the latest `requests` module of version 2.22.0. It really is a Python version issue.

Comment: @blhsing 3.7.3 on macOS

Comment: @wim I just installed 3.7.3 in Windows and I got a 200 just like you did. It really is an issue specific to certain Python versions.

Comment: Then it is probably due to different openssl (`ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION`).  You don't need all those headers to repro, just a plain old get(url) will do it.

Comment: O.P. please update your question with micro version numbers, i.e. the output of `python2 -V` and `python3 -V`, and also the ssl version in each.

Comment: @wim was using latest version
3.7.4 with OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019 | 
2.7.16 with OpenSSL 1.0.2q  20 Nov 2018
sorry if replay was late :|

Comment: [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58284829/difference-in-status-of-the-same-request-over-tor-in-python3-6-and-python3-7)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the exception thrown by urlib3:

> /home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:1004:
>   InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding
>   certificate verification is strongly advised. See:
>   https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
>   InsecureRequestWarning,

According to the [latest release notes, section 1.25.5 (2019-09-19)](https://pypi.org/project/urllib3/#id5):

> Add mitigation for BPO-37428 **affecting Python <3.7.4 and OpenSSL**
>   1.1.1+ which caused certificate verification to be enabled when using cert_reqs=CERT_NONE. (Issue #**1682**)

You can follow the [issue on Github](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/1682), it has been closed.

**TLDR**

[User @sethmlarson on Github](https://github.com/sethmlarson) found this bug on **urllib3**:

> create_urllib3_context():

```py
    # Enable post-handshake authentication for TLS 1.3, see GH #1634. PHA is
    # necessary for conditional client cert authentication with TLS 1.3.
    # The attribute is None for OpenSSL <= 1.1.0 or does not exist in older
    # versions of Python.
    if getattr(context, "post_handshake_auth", None) is not None:
        context.post_handshake_auth = True
```

setting this value to `True` will enable verification of server certificates, instead of being disabled.